# Visually matching lines between two monaco editors

Tags: javascript, typescript, monaco-editor

Is there a way to visually match lines between two monaco editors? E.g. if line 5 wraps in editor A, editor B's line 5 should take up two lines as well even if it doesn't wrap.

This is done in diff mode, I am trying to create something similar.